# in stylus,use undefined function,not throw any error

Tags: stylus

for example,
stylus file:

```
.dd
  fun() 
  height:10px
```

and I use nodejs to complie it

```
var stylus = require('stylus');
var s = stylus(stylusCode);
s.render(function(err, css) {
  if (err) {
    grunt.log.error(err);
    grunt.fail.warn('Stylus failed to compile.');
    callback(css, true);
  } else {
    callback(css, null);
  }
});
```

in stylus file,"fun" function is undefined,I want it throw a error,but not.

Comment: not possible due to how stylus works